# jQuery multiple Attribute selector with find() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

jQuery Version 1.11.1

Bootstrap Version 3.1.1

HTML

```html
<i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="hover focus"></i>
<i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="hover focus"></i>
<i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click" data-title="click"></i>
<i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click" data-title="click"></i>
```

JS

```html
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip()
  .find("[data-trigger='click']")
  .on("click", function(e) {
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip'][data-trigger='click']").not(this).tooltip("hide");
  });

// true
// $("[data-toggle='tooltip'][data-trigger='click']").length === 2
// false
// $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip().find("[data-trigger='click']").length === 2
```

I know can use

```js
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
$("[data-toggle='tooltip'][data-trigger='click']").on("click", function(e) {
  $("[data-toggle='tooltip'][data-trigger='click']").not(this).tooltip("hide");
});
```

Why the first code can not use find()?

Comment: Just swap out `find` with `filter` and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) searches the *descendants* of the selected objects, not the selected objects themselves. Your selector is obtaining all the  elements anyway.

As @adeneo has stated,[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is probably what you are looking for, in order to only select the elements with the `data-trigger="click"` attribute

i.e.

```js
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip()
  .filter("[data-trigger='click']")
  .on("click", function(e) {
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is what you need not .find()
It reduces the currently selected elements to those that match the selector

```
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip()
  .filter("[data-trigger='click']")
  .on("click", function(e) {
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip'][data-trigger='click']").not(this).tooltip("hide");
});
```